# Crystal reports: is there a way to regex in crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report function which requires me to trim off characters which start with a "-" and delete the rest following the the "-" (dash).

For example, I would have order number 00000112345-C43-PJ.

How would I just trim off everything from the right of the "-" get the result as 00000112345?

I looked for a regex and substring but crystal doesn't seem to have these functions available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crystal might not have regex but it certainly has all the basic string functions

Something like this should do it for you (not tested):

```
Left({OrderNumber}, InStr({OrderNumber}, "-") - 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

I've recently added a regex library here:- https://sourceforge.net/projects/cruflregex/files/

It's a bit minimal, but might be of use to someone.

Comment: +1  Nice.  You may want to post the source file in SourceForge instead of an archive of the source.

Comment: @craig Good point, thanks for the feedback. You see lots of downloads of these things but no-one ever says anything. It's nice to hear that someone has looked at it.

Comment: Have you tested this with Crystal Reports 12?  Is the .PDB file required for the .DLL to function?

Comment: @craig PDB is only for debugging symbols so you don't need it. I haven't tested with CR 12 as I don't have it.

Comment: For Crystal Reports 2008 (v 12.x), the DLL (u25regex.dll) needs to be deployed in the `C:\Program Files\Business Objects\BusinessObjects Enterprise 12.0\win32_x86` directory.

Comment: @user159335, while `RxMatch( "foo 08/01/2012 bar", "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}" )` returns True, `RxGetMatches( "foo 08/01/2012 bar", "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}" )[1]` generates an array-bounds error.  Ubound( `RxGetMatches( "foo 08/01/2012 bar", "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}" )[1]` ) equals 0, when it should equal 1.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This hasn't been a feature in Crystal reports for a while.  I heard it might be a feature in the latest crystal reports (16?).  Check out their website and give them a call, they shouldn't charge for a pre-sales question.

Another approach you could take to this is to manually process the value and validate it using the string and isvalue functions, etc.  Messier, but it might be a backup option.